# Horizontal div scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create an action using HTML, CSS and JS, when you scroll horizontally on a div.

This code which I found on w3Schools is what I was looking for, but I can not modify it to accept horizontal scroll. Basically it needs to indicate which image is on screen (1 or 2) using lets say dots.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("myP").className = "test";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myP").className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 1500px;
}

#myP {
  position: fixed;
}

.test {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>The onscroll Event</h1>

<p id="myP">
  If you scroll 50 pixels down from the top of this page, the class "test" is added to this paragraph. Scroll up again to remove the class.
</p>
```

I tried to modify the code from previous link and some others, but without success. This code seem to be the closest to what I need.

Comment: Could you include the code that you have that is closest so far?

Comment: What does "To be more specific in a div." mean? Can you extrapolate?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Have you tried using `document.documentElement.scrollLeft` instead of `....scrollTop`?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work horizontally make the page content wider than the viewport, in the example I simply set its `width` to `5000px`, and change `scrollTop` in the JS logic to `scrollLeft`.

Also note that the code quality from W3Schools is very rarely of good quality. It's for this reason I would strongly suggest you avoid them and use a better resource, such as MDN.

To improve the quality of the code in your example you can avoid using `onscroll` or any of the other event properties. Use `addEventListener()` instead. In addition use the `classList` collection to add/remove/toggle classes on elements.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('#myP');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  p.classList.toggle('test', document.documentElement.scrollLeft > 50) 
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 5000px;
}

#myP {
  position: fixed;
}

.test {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>The onscroll Event</h1>

<p id="myP">
  If you scroll 50 pixels from the left of this page, the class "test" is added to this paragraph. Scroll right again to remove the class.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To highlight the text when horizontally scrolling, you firstly adjust the width:

```
<body style="font-size:20px;width:1500px">
```

This makes sure there is enough space to scroll horizontally.

After you have done that, to apply the effect when scrolling, instead of `scrollUp` you use `scrollLeft` like this:

```
  if (document.documentElement.scrollLeft > 50) {
```

This should highlight the text when scrolling horizontally 50 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve horizontal scrolling detection and indicate which image is currently on the screen, you'll need to make a few adjustments to your code

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var scrollPosition = window.scrollX; // Horizontal scroll position

    // Calculate which image is currently in view
    var containerWidth = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
    var imageIndex = Math.floor(scrollPosition / containerWidth);

    // Update dots to indicate current image
    var dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
    dots.forEach(function(dot, index) {
      if (index === imageIndex) {
        dot.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        dot.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });
  });

  // Add dots for each image
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var numImages = container.children.length;
  var dotsContainer = document.getElementById('dots');
  for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
    var dot = document.createElement('span');
    dot.classList.add('dot');
    dotsContainer.appendChild(dot);
  }
```

```css
 body {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #container {
    width: 200vw; /* Make the container twice as wide as the viewport */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent line breaks */
    font-size: 0; /* Remove whitespace between inline-block elements */
  }

  .image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100vw; /* Each image takes the full width of the viewport */
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }

  .dot {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .dot.active {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('image1.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('image2.jpg');"></div>
</div>

<div id="dots"></div>
```

In this code:

- Two images are placed horizontally within a container.
- Each image takes the full width of the viewport, and the container is made twice as wide as the viewport to accommodate both images.
- The JavaScript code calculates the current scroll position (scrollPosition) and determines which image is currently in view by dividing the scroll position by the container width.
- Dots are added dynamically to indicate the current image, and their
  color changes to yellow when the corresponding image is in view.